# Objective-C : Create 2 custom cells in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a tableview which contains:

-2 custom cells : **redCell** and **blueCell**

-2 buttons : **redButton** and **blueButton** at bottom of the screen.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        if(indexPath.section == 0) {
            RedTableViewCell *redCell = (RedTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:BlockListTableViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
            Red *red = (Red *)[self.reds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            return redCell;
        }
        else
        {
            BlueTableViewCell *blueCell = (BlueTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:RestBlockTableViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
            Blue *blue = [self.blues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            return blueCell;
        }

        return nil;
    }
```

[My TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1ZG4.png)

I want that when i click **redButton** = **redCell** added ,click **blueButton** = **blueCell** added.

P/S : I don't want to change the background color, I want 2 different cells.

Comment: Please if my question deserve downvotes I want to know why so i can improve myself .Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear, and doesn't show any tries from your part. (PS: I didn't down vote, but that could be the reason)

Comment: @Larme Thank you. I will edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the below from your unclear questions.

The red cell contains a red button, and when you click on this red button, you want a new red cell to be added. Similarly with Blue cell.

**Solution:**

Inside, red(or blue) button action,

1. Add new entry in your self.reds(or self.blues) array
2. reload tableview

Also, check, numberofRowsinSection  should return self.reds.count for section 0 and self.blues.count for other sections.